# Vuejs DOM not updating if the event is fired from $on method

Tags: vue.js

I'm guessing that it has to do something with Vue not detecting the changes in the tracks object.

```
mounted(){
        Event.$emit('requestCurrentTrack');
        Event.$on('currentSong', (data) => this.fetchAlbum(data)); //Data from this method won't output on the screen.

        this.fetchAlbum(); // Data from this method out will output to the screen
    },
methods:{
        fetchAlbum(){
            axios.get('/api/album/'+this.id).then((response)=>{
                this.album = response.data[1][0];
                this.tracks = response.data[0];
                this.artistName = this.tracks[0].artist;
            });
        },
        play(data, index){
            if(data){
              Event.$emit('playTrack', data, index);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The `Event.$on` method is simply setting the event handler callback function. That function won't get called until the `currentSong` event is emitted, which you aren't doing anywhere in the code you've shared. Also, you're passing `data` to the `this.fetchAlbum` method, but that method doesn't take in a parameter.

Comment: @thanksd is correct

Answer (score 1):

> You have to learn more about event bus.Take a look to [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

To use event bus take a look below:

In `main.js` you have to create the event bus

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export const eventBus = new Vue() //creating the event bus

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

A rendered component,lets name it `childOne.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="clicked">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { eventBus } from '../main'
    export default {
    name: 'child-one',
    methods: {
      clicked () {
        eventBus.$emit('eventName', 'text passed through event bus') //creating the event with the name eventName and pass a text
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Another rendered component lets name it `childTwo.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- some html here -->  
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { eventBus } from '../main'
    export default {
    name: 'child-two',
      created() {
        eventBus.$on('eventName', dataPassed => { //listening to event with name eventName
        console.log(dataPassed)
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Note** the eventBus will work only if your components are rendered.So to make this example to work you can do it by importing the two components in `App.vue` and registrering them